# web2py using guest account to submit record

Tags: web2py

I'm using web2py to build a web app.
I want to have a feature which when the user is not login, all the record created by the user (and submitted to the database) is marked as created by guest.

Right now in my table:

```
Field('Owner',db.auth_user,default=auth.user_id),
```

when the user is login, it will set Owner to the user account.

But when the user isn't login, this record is null.

Is there anyway I could link the record to a Guest account when the user is not login?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do it.
Basically muse use the "default=" in Field.
And also set both the field writable and readable to false.

```
Field('Owner',db.auth_user,default=(auth.user_id if auth.is_logged_in() else 'guessAccountId')),
 ...
db.url.Owner.readable = db.url.Owner.writable = False
```